# Eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a specific linear transformation

Tags: polynomials, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, partial-derivative

I am working on the following problem:

Let $k$ be a field, let $d$ be a positive integer, and let $P_d$ be the $k$-vector space of polynomials of degree $\leq d$ in $k[x,y]$. Compute the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the linear transformation $x\frac{d}{dx} - y\frac{d}{dy} : P_d \longrightarrow P_d$.

So far in my Linear Algebra class, we've only computed eigenvalues and eigenvectors of linear transformations from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$ by considering the associated $n \times n$ matrix so far. Thus, I wasn't sure exactly how to approach this one.

But, I tried approaching this just like the other problems we've done. So, in order to find the eigenvalues, we want to find $\lambda \in k$ such that $Tf = \lambda f$, where $f$ is a (nonzero) function in $k[x,y]$ (which would serve as an eigenvector) and $T$ is the linear transformation specified above. This gives *$x\frac{df}{dx} - y\frac{df}{dy} = \lambda f$.

How can I now solve equation * for eigenvalues and the associated eigenvectors ? Am I supposed to solve a corresponding differential equation? Even this is tough for me, since I'm not used to solving differential equations for functions in two variables. Or is there an easier approach that I'm not seeing?

I wouldn't think that I'm supposed to expand $f$ out to include all of its terms and solve from there -- this can get cumbersome since we're dealing with the polynomial ring in two variables $k[x,y]$.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried plugging in a $d$-dimensional polynomial for your function for $f$?

Comment: Hint: the operator $x{df\over dx}$ multiples each term by the exponent of $x$ in that term.

Comment: @Gregory So, say I take $d = 1$. Then, a typical polynomial $f \in k[x,y]$ is of the form $f(x,y) = ax + by + cxy + e$ for $a,b,c,e \in k$. $x\frac{df}{dx} - y\frac{df}{dy} = \lambda f$ then gives $x(a + cy) - y(b + cx) = \lambda (ax + by + cxy + e) \Rightarrow ax - by= \lambda ax + \lambda by + \lambda cxy + \lambda e$. Where do I go from here ? If I match up coefficients on the left and right-hand side, it doesn't seem that there is an actual solution for $\lambda$.

Comment: What about setting $c = e = 0$ and $\lambda = 1$? You've shown your eigenvector is $a x + by$ with eigenvalue $\lambda = 1$

Comment: This is analogous to requiring your eigenvector be of a certain form to satisfy a matrix eigenvalue problem.

Comment: @Gregory I see -- interesting! I hadn't seen that technique before, to come up with a certain eigenvector while simultaneously coming up with a certain eigenvalue. For $d = 2$ I get an equation that looks like $2ax^2 - hxy^2 + iy^2 + cx - 2by^2 - ey = \lambda(ax^2 + by^2 + cx + ey + fxy + gx^2y^2 + hxy^2 + ix^2y + j)$. The term $2ax^2$ on the left-hand side requires $\lambda = 2$, while the term $cx$ on the LHS requires $\lambda = 1$ -- so I think there's no solution for $d = 2$. Is there a way to see that this behavior persists for all $d \geq 2$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a general $d$ dimensional polynomial
$$ f(x,y) = \sum_{i=0}^d \sum_{j=0}^d a_{ij} x^i y^j. $$
Plugging into our linear operator we obtain
$$ \sum_{i=0}^d \sum_{j=0}^d (i-j -\lambda) a_{ij} x^i y^j = 0. $$
Since this needs to hold for each coefficient of $x^i y^j$, we require $(i-j -\lambda)a_{ij} = 0$ to hold for all $i,j$. This immediately implies that the eigenvalues will satisfy $\lambda = \pm n$ for $n = 0, 1, \dots, d$. To find the eigenvectors use the relation that $i-j = \lambda$ and all other $i,j$ pairs will have $a_{ij} = 0$. We obtain the eigenvectors
$$\sum_{i-j=\lambda} a_{ij} x^i y^j.$$

**EDIT:**
For example $\lambda = 0$, we have the eigenvector $\sum_{i=0}^d a_{ii} (x y)^i$. In the comments you made it should have been $\lambda = 1$ and $a x$ or $\lambda = -1$ and $b y$.

Comment: Thanks. I think the main disconnect I had here was not seeing how to write a general polynomial in $k[x,y]$, as you did above with the double sum. That's very helpful and opens up a lot of doors. (=

Comment: is there a typo in your summation? Shouldn't the lower index in the sum read $i - j = \lambda$ ?

Comment: Yes thank you. Nice catch.